# Pack Electron in existing App

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

i'm kinda new to electron and tried a few things with it. I'm currently working on a bigger project with a lot of existing code, where we want to integrate electron to our application. I made a extension for our app which is directly loaded and used **require('electron')** to get the things started.
I cannot get electron to work because i'm running this from node.
I have experimented with the electron-quick-start and when i run **electron-quick-start** with **electron .** it works without problems, but i cannot run it with **node main.js**.

Is there a way to pack electron in an existing app or is the only way to use electron to wrap the application into electron?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pack electron in an existing app or is the only way to use electron to wrap the application into electron?

Well, the answer to that is probably yes but which way to start from would be more convenient or appropriate for an existing application is an entirely different matter. Personally what I'd do would be instead of requiring electron in your existing app, to create a new Electron app that would include the needed UI and that would require your existing modules, so instead of requiring the UI from your existing module, I would require your existing module from the UI app. Of course not having seen even a single line of code and not knowing anything bout your app I cannot say for sure that it would be a good approach.

Comment: thx for the quick answer. In my opinion it is definitly not a good approach to wrap the existing application in electron because the gui is a optional feature. Additionally our project should be able to be ported to e.g. ARMv8 Devices which is not supported by electron. In this cases, we would just disable the GUI feature. So my conclusion: if there is a way to include electron in an existing project, how is this done, because i have really no idea?

Comment: @JohannesPinger Did you find any info about that? I'm looking for the same